# Insanity during the creation of a Core Data entity

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am populating a core data entity programmatically.

I have an array like this:

```
NSArray *formats = @[
                        @"6 x 5",
                        @"5.3 x 4.3",
                        @"4 x 3",
                        @"5 x 3.5",
...
```

Now I enumerate that and populate the entity

```
  for (int i=0; i<[formats count]; i++) {

    NSString *format = formats[i];
    Format *oneFormat = [Format formatWithString:format inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    // ... bla bla

  }
```

Inside the Format class I have

```
+ (Format *)formatWithString:(NSString *)string inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{

    Format *aFormat = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(name == %@)", string];
```

This is the problem. At one point inside the `for` loop I have

```
format = @"5.3 x 4.3"
```

then, this line is executed

```
    Format *oneFormat = [Format formatWithString:format inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

in theory, `format = @"5.3 x 4.3"` is passed to `Format formatWithString`.

The problem is that  `Format formatWithString` receives the following string: `@"4 x 3.5"`.

What??? A method is called `@"5.3 x 4.3"` and receives `@"4 x 3.5"`?

And here comes the amazing part. If I `po predicate` I see

```
name == "5.3 x 4.3 cm"
```

That is the correct value. But when the record is saved, the wrong value is the one saved.

This `@"4 x 3.5"` was an old format I had on the code ages ago. It was a typo. I removed all mentions of this format from my code. I have checked that 10 times. There is no `@"4 x 3.5"` anymore.

I have deleted all derived data. Every time I generate the database it contains this `@"4 x 3.5"` entry that should not be there.

Is there any hidden core data cache or some place I can clean to generate that correctly? How can a method be called with one value and receive another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I suspect you are not deleting the SQLite file when you reset everything.  If you are on iOS then it will be in the simulator or on the device. Deleting the app from the device/sim works too.  If you are on OS X then track down where the SQLite file is stored and delete it.
2. Doing update/insert queries like this are horribly expensive.  I would recommend doing ONE fetch for all of the objects that you need to made a decision about.  Otherwise your performance will be terrible.

Comment: #2 give me the idea to change the variable names inside the Format class and that solved the problem. Thanks.